# onchange event not tracking properly

Tags: javascript

I have a form that I want to track any changes. Right now I have it set so when the user exits the page, an alert box displays saying how many changes were made to the form. However, it keeps registering 0. I've tested with adding an alert to the inputChanges function telling me a change has occurred and the alert fires, but the count still registers as 0 when I exit the page...

Here's my script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var totalChanges = "";
    var inputHandles = 0;
    var selectHandles = 0;
    var textAreaHandles = 0;

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    alert("Total Form Changes:" + totalChanges);
}//onbeforeunload

   var totalChanges = inputHandles + selectHandles + textAreaHandles;

   function inputChanges() {
   inputHandles++; 
   alert("Change");
   }

   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
   for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    inputs[i].onchange = inputChanges;
   }    

   function selectChanges(){
   selectHandles++;
   }

   var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
   for (i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
   selects[i].onselect = selectChanges;
  }

  function textAreaChanges(){
   textAreaHandles++;
  }

   var textAreas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
  for (i = 0; i < textAreas.length; i++){
   textAreas[i].onchange = textAreaChanges;
  }
}//Onload
```

Comment: There seems to be an extra quotation mark in this line: `alert(""Total Form Changes:" + totalChanges);`

Comment: Thanks, I took out a part of the script that doesn't pertain to this post and it was left in there... so irrelevant but good catch.

Comment: Onselect? Try onchange

Comment: Why do you initialize totalChanges to "" instead of 0? That is probably not helping, since you're using that variable for numeric values, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `totalChanges` here:

```
var totalChanges = "";
```

...and then re-declare it here:

```
var totalChanges = inputHandles + selectHandles + textAreaHandles;
```

...at which point the things you're adding up are all `0`.

You need to do that calculation at the point where you need the value:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    totalChanges = inputHandles + selectHandles + textAreaHandles;
    alert("Total Form Changes:" + totalChanges);
}
```

Or set `totalChanges = 0` initially and then increment it every time the other variables change, but that's clunkier.

Note also that you're not tallying the number of fields that now have values different to their starting values, you're tallying the number of individual edits. So if the user changes a field twice with the second change being back to the original value your code will track that as two changes (when logically it's kind of zero changes).

Answer (score 0):

Since the user can change values back to what they were, I suggest you compare all `input.value` with `input.defaultValue` and check `select.options[select.selectedIndex]defaultSelected`

also you might want to move the } and the alert to after the sum of total changes

something like this

```
window.onload = function() {
  var totalChanges = 0;


  window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); // ditto for "textarea"
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      totaChanges +=  inputs[i].value != inputs[i].defaultValue;
    }    
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
      totalChanges += !selects[i].defaultSelected;
   }

    alert("Total Form Changes:" + totalChanges);
  }//onbeforeunload
}
```